# Alinear imágenes seguidas

Tags: html, css

He estado buscando soluciones para poder alinear imágenes en una página web. Lo que busco es que se alineen seguidas una de otra.

Lo que sucede es que estoy obteniendo los datos, incluidas las imágenes, de una base de datos mediante `PHP` y `JSON`. Todo funciona de maravilla, solamente que al yo traerme los datos en el `foreach`, evidentemente, cada imagen me la inserta con un salto de linea.

Lo que busco es que no me dé este salto y yo poder elegir 3 imágenes por linea o 4 ( se que la solución puede estar en `CSS`, `HTML` o incluso `PHP`, solo que no se me ocurre cómo poder lograr esto).

```
foreach ( $obj as $res ) {

    $n = $res->nom;
    $lk = $res->img_url;
    $p = $res->precio;

    echo "<h1 id='t'> $n </h1>";
    echo "<img src=$lk id='im2'>";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Una manera sencilla seria usando CSS
- crear un `div` padre con `x` cantidad de `div` hijos generados mediante **PHP**,
- que esos div hijos contendrían las imágenes con su respectivos nombres, algo así

Código

```
<style>
    .gallery {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .gallery .picture {
        margin: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 80px;
    }
</style>

<div class="gallery">
<?php
    foreach ( $obj as $res ) {
        $n = $res->nom;
        $lk = $res->img_url;
        $p = $res->precio;
        echo '<div class="picture">';
        echo "<h1 id='t'> $n </h1>";
        echo "<img src=$lk id='im2'>";
        echo "</div>"
    }
?>
</div>
```

Editado: me faltado añadir el cierra de el `div` padre

Editado: añadí `text-align` para centrar los `divs` hijos

Answer (score 0):

Una imagen tiene `display: inline` por defecto. Observa el siguiente snippet:

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/workbench.jpg" width="32%" />
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/coffee.jpg" width="32%" />
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/sound.jpg" width="32%" />
```

Lo que está sucediendo es que estás insertando elementos `h1`, y los elementos de título por defecto tienen `display: block`. Esto es lo que está haciendo que tus imágenes pasen a una nueva línea:

```html
<h2>Imagen 1</h2>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/workbench.jpg" width="32%" />
<h2>Imagen 2</h2>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/coffee.jpg" width="32%" />
<h2>Imagen 3</h2>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/sound.jpg" width="32%" />
```

Para lograr lo que quieres hay varias soluciones, pero si no necesitas soportar Internet Explorer 9, una muy versátil es hacer uso de [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox) en el contenedor de las imágenes y situar cada título y cada imagen dentro de contenedores independientes:

```
echo "<div class='contenedor'>";
foreach ( $obj as $res ) {

    $n = $res->nom;
    $lk = $res->img_url;
    $p = $res->precio;

    echo "<div class='imagen'>";
        echo "<h1 id='t'> $n </h1>";
        echo "<img src=$lk id='im2'>";
    echo "</div>";

}
echo "</div>";
```

Aquí te dejo el resultado con el código `CSS` necesario:

> En este ejemplo estoy utilizando solo tres imágenes por fila haciendo uso de [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis), [flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) y [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap). Si quisieras un número diferente de imágenes por fila, modificando el valor de `flex-basis` lo puedes conseguir.

```css
.contenedor {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contenedor img {
    width: 100%;
}

.imagen {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.imagen h5 {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="imagen">
    <h5>Imagen 1</h5>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/workbench.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imagen">
    <h5>Imagen 2</h5>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/coffee.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imagen">
    <h5>Imagen 3</h5>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/sound.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imagen">
    <h5>Imagen 4</h5>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/workbench.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imagen">
    <h5>Imagen 5</h5>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/coffee.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="imagen">
    <h5>Imagen 6</h5>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/sound.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Las razones del comportamiento ya te las explico el amigo @ElChiniNet así que solo trataré de aportar una *solución*

Opciones tienes varias como ya te comentaron en las otras 2 respuestas, sin embargo considero que por simpleza, deberías considerar *crear una rejilla* con CSS Grid.

Del modo siguiente:

- Crea un contenedor principal con la clase por ejemplo `.imagenes`
- Indicamos el número de columnas deseadas con `grid-template-columns` para que en este caso el diseño sea de 2 columnas
- Como queremos mostrar tanto un `h1` como una imagen por cada posición, entonces encerramos en un `div` ambos valores por cada cuadro que deseamos mostrar.

Quedando así:

```
  <div class="imagenes">
    <div class="imagen">
      <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
      <img src="ruta_a_tu_imagen" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imagen"> 
      <h1>Hola Mundo 2</h1>
      <img src="ruta_a_tu_imagen" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imagen"> 
      <h1>Hola Mundo 2</h1>
      <img src="ruta_a_tu_imagen" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imagen">
      <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
      <img src="ruta_a_tu_imagen" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imagen"> 
      <h1>Hola Mundo 2</h1>
      <img src="ruta_a_tu_imagen" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="imagen"> 
      <h1>Hola Mundo 2</h1>
      <img src="ruta_a_tu_imagen" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Finalmente las reglas CSS se verían de este modo:

```
.imagenes{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}
```

- Al encerrar tanto el `h1` dentro de un `div` en el sistema de rejillas, su propiedad `display: block;` solo aplicará al 100% del ancho de su contenedor padre que sería el `div` con clase `imagen`